# How do I return the element in a list that evaluate to true?

Tags: python, boolean, list-comprehension

For example,
if I wanted to know what numbers are divisible by 2 and had

`test_list = [6, 4, 8, 9, 10]`
`print([number % 2 == 0 for number in test_list])`

which would evaluate to:

`[True, True, True, False, True]`

What can I do to get the elements that evaluate to True in a list?
Like this:

`[6, 4, 8, 10]`

(in python)

Comment: Just add an if condition to comprehension `print([n for n in test_list if n % 2 == 0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you where very close to the solution. In your list comprehension you told the program to put in the list not `number`, the actual member of your list, but `number % 2 == 0`, that is of course a `bool` type.

To get the list you want, you have to tell the comprehension to get `number` from `test_list` each time the condition you want is met (in your case that it's even)

```
print([number for number in test_list if number % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
print([x for x in test_list if x % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: Did you test this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension

```
print([num for num in test_list if num % 2 == 0])
```

```
[6, 4, 8, 10]
```